# Counting number of fields in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am counting the number of fields in a row and spit out the row if the number of fields are more than the expected number of fields as below

```
awk -F”,” ‘{ if ( NF != ‘${x}’ ) print}’ filename
```

Where x is the expected number of fields.
But this is throwing error if the file has more than 100 fields. What is the alternative approach for this.

Sample data:

```
1,aaaa,bbbb
2,aaaa,bbbb,cccc
3,aaaa,bbbb
```

Expected output

The line which has more than 3 fields should be displayed

```
2,aaaa,bbbb,cccc
```

The main issue here is my file has more than 100 columns and awk is throwing error as it has 100 fields limitation.

Comment: All quotes are wrong. Use `"` and `'`.

Comment: See: [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/3776858)

Comment: In combination to the comment of Cyrus, the curly braces around `$x` lead to a syntax error as it would read as `{ if (NF != {5}) print}` when `x=5`.

Comment: @kvantour: Yes, I hadn't noticed that at all. Possibly he/she meant `${x}` instead of `{$x}`.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: Just edited my question with sample data. Won’t be able to post the real data as the file is more than 2 gb.

Comment: Which version of awk are you using and on which operating system are you executing this?

Comment: When I do man awk I can see 2010 as the year and is unix

Comment: See if you have `gawk` installed and use it instead.

Comment: Are you by any chance on Solaris and running the default awk from /usr/bin? If so - don't do that as that is old, broken awk. Use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead. If that's not the problem then get GNU awk.

Comment: Thanks Ed , using the awk in the different path worked fine. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ x=3; awk -F, -v c="$x" 'NF!=c' file

2,aaaa,bbbb,cccc
```

if your `awk` has number of field limitation, here is a detour

```
$ grep -on , file | 
  awk -F: -v c="$x" '{a[$1]++} END{for(k in a) if(a[k]!=c) print k}' | 
  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} FNR in a' - file

2,aaaa,bbbb,cccc
```

the two `awk` scripts don't parse the large file and should not depend number of fields limitation.